# How to replace "Verfügar Datum unter" (in english: "available date") with "Zugriff Datum unter" (in english: "date accessed") in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texstudio, apa-style, latex3

I use teXstudio with MiKTeC and Biblatex with apa

My texfile:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,listof=totoc,glossary=totoc,parskip=half,toc=bibliography]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = black,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
    Hier beginnt mein Dokument \autocite{Nature2017}.
    \printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

My bibfile:

```
@online{Nature2017,
    editor = {Philip Campbell},
    publisher={Macmillan Publishers Ltd.},
    title = {Nature},
    location={Great Britain},
    url = {https://www.nature.com/nature/},
    urldate = {2017-12-02},
}
```

My result:

[image: My result]

The desired result is like

Campbell, P. (Hrsg.). (n.d.). Nature. Zugriff 2. Dezember 2017 unter https://....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\DefineBibliographyStrings` (in the preamble) is the tool to override  default strings. The string in use here is `retrieved` (defined by the apa style).

Unrelated: `hyperref` should be loaded last, with very few exceptions (most notble: `cleveref`). I also took the liberty to simplify the `geometry` parameters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,listof=totoc,glossary=totoc,parskip=half,toc=bibliography]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
 retrieved = {Zugriff}}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = black,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    Hier beginnt mein Dokument \autocite{Nature2017}.

    \printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) This is exactly the solution I need.